# Test multiple cases based on propsdata in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs

I have a component that has a a button that only shows when an `article.link` prop is not empty. I want to write a test to check the button is rendered when the `article.link` is not empty and another one for when it is empty
my component looks like so :

```
a.btn.plutus_btn-primary.round( v-if="hasArticleLink" target='_blank' :href="articleLink") Start Shopping Now
```

`hasArticleLink` is a computed property that return true when the link is not empty.
The unit test I wrote looks like this :

```
    it("should not renders the link button when article doesn't have a link", () => {
    wrapper = mount(MerchandisingArticle, {
      propsData: {
        article: {
          link: ""
        }
      }
    });
    expect(wrapper.find("a").exists()).toBe(false);
  });
  it("renders the linked button when article has link", () => {
    wrapper = mount(MerchandisingArticle, {
      propsData: {
        article: {
          link: "https://google.com"
        }
      }
    });
    expect(wrapper.find("a").exists()).toBe(true);
  });
```

that works just fine but I was wondering if there is a better way to test these reversed cases as I think this one is kinda duplicated since I have to mount the component in every `it` bloc ? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I Think it's good to mount the component before every test, because this way there will be no sideeffects to a new test from a previous one.
But you could do something like this to not duplicate code:

```
const expectedValues = [
        { link: '', expects: false },
        { link: 'www.google.com', expects: true },
         ....
    ]

    expectedValues.forEach(({ link, expects }) => {
        it(`should evaluate ${expects} for link:${link} `, () => {
            const wrapper = mount(MerchandisingArticle, {
                propsData: {
                    article: {
                       link
                    }
                }
            })

            expect(wrapper.find("a").exists()).to.equal(expects);
        })
    })
```

This way you can also easily add new test cases.